# Sliding of finger to the right on item of ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to create a ListView where sliding of the finger to the right  on item of list open inner layer of item, where  user can enter text  to EditText. Like this video ([1min 10 sec](http://youtu.be/U9FEVmkSHBo?t=1m5s)).

Any ideas how to do it. thanks

Comment: you mean like in facebook and youtube??

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: don`t understand your question.

Comment: David Wasser, I'm trying to create, but I do not know how to implement animation when sliding.